# What are possible backup status in velero?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, backup

I am using velero for k8s cluster backup. I was looking for possible backup status in velero.
I couldn't find any proper documentation on this. Can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

As I see in Velero code (version: v.1.5.3), the backups can have the following phases:

- New
- FailedValidation
- InProgress
- Completed
- PartiallyFailed
- Failed
- Deleting

see: https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/blob/v1.5.3/pkg/apis/velero/v1/backup.go#L195

Restores have these phases:

- New
- FailedValidation
- InProgress
- Completed
- PartiallyFailed
- Failed

see: https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/blob/v1.5.3/pkg/apis/velero/v1/restore.go#L184

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version the files for finding the phases have changed. Also new phases have bee n added:

### Backup Phases

- New
- FailedValidation
- InProgress
- WaitingForPluginOperations
- WaitingForPluginOperationsPartiallyFailed
- Finalizing
- FinalizingPartiallyFailed
- Completed
- PartiallyFailed
- Failed
- Deleting

see: https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/blob/433daa18bd76548d14d38fea3af6d3b64f0bc9a5/pkg/apis/velero/v1/backup_types.go#L276

### Restore Phases

- New
- FailedValidation
- InProgress
- WaitingForPluginOperations
- WaitingForPluginOperationsPartiallyFailed
- Completed
- PartiallyFailed
- Failed

see: https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/blob/433daa18bd76548d14d38fea3af6d3b64f0bc9a5/pkg/apis/velero/v1/restore_types.go#L229